# how to set rmse cost function in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have cost function in tensorflow.

```
activation = tf.add(tf.mul(X, W), b)
cost = (tf.pow(Y-y_model, 2)) # use sqr error for cost function
```

I am trying out [this example](https://github.com/nlintz/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/1_linear_regression.py). How can I change it to rmse cost function?

Comment: Hi @Viki , can you accept my answer!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.subtract(targets, outputs))))
```

And slightly simplified (TensorFlow overloads the most important operators):

```
tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean((targets - outputs)**2))
```

Comment: Done, Actually I had 2 accounts by mistake so had to get that merged. + it only got merged because you asked for the acceptance. So thanks for the answer and for reminding :)

Answer (score 15):

The formula for [root mean square error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation) is:

[image]

The way to implement it in TF is `tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(Y1, Y2)))`.

---

The important thing to remember is that there is no need to minimize RMSE loss with the optimizer. With the same result you can minimize just `tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(Y1, Y2))` or even `tf.reduce_sum(tf.squared_difference(Y1, Y2))` but because they have a smaller graph of operations, they will be optimized faster.

But you can use this function if you just want to tract the value of RMSE.

Answer (score 8):

Now we have `tf.losses.mean_squared_error`

Therefore,

```
RMSE = tf.sqrt(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(label, prediction))
```

Answer (score 6):

(1)  Are you sure you need this?  Minimizing the [l2 loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/l2_loss) will give you the same result as minimizing the RMSE error.  (Walk through the math:  You don't need to take the square root, because minimizing x^2 still minimizes x for x>0, and you know that the sum of a bunch of squares is positive. Minimizing x*n minimizes x for constant n).

(2)  If you need to know the numerical value of the RMSE error, then  implement it directly from the [definition of RMSE](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~susan/courses/s60/split/node60.html):

```
tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(...)/n)
```

(You need to know or calculate n - the number of elements in the sum, and set the reduction axis appropriately in the call to reduce_sum).

Comment: @dga Wouldn't `tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(...))` be a better option here?

Comment: @goelakash - probably!  I had been trying for the most clear transliteration of the typical RMSE formula that I linked, but in practice, `tf.reduce_mean` is a better choice.

Comment: Since you seem quite into the loss calculation you might be able to help me out with this question: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44717224/when-using-rmse-loss-in-tensorflow-i-receive-very-small-loss-values-smalerl-than) @dga

Comment: @dga About point (1): I have a case when MSE's behavior is desired but it's value goes too small like 0.001 and results it's derivative to be too small. That results very small learning. Would this be a valid use case for RMSE for training purpose?

Answer (score 5):

for who want to implement RMSE as a metric

```
rmse = tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()
```

exapmle of how to use it

```
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=[rmse,'mae'])
```