# When using RMSE loss in TensorFlow I receive very small loss values smalerl than 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, caffe, euclidean-distance, mean-square-error

Hello I have a network that produces logits / outputs like this:

```
logits = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 128, 64, 64]) // outputs
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 128, 64, 64]) // ground_truth, targets
```

--> y ground truth values are downscaled from `[0, 255] to [0, 1]` in order to increase perforce as I have read it is better to use range `[0, 1]`

Now I want to calculate the RMSE / EuclideanLoss like this:

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(logits - y))
```

or

```
loss = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.subtract(y, logits))))
```

not sure which one is better.

When doing so my loss values start at roughly `1.` and then quickly go down to `2.5e-4`. When I use the `EuclideanLoss` in Caffe for the same network my loss values starts from roughly `1000` and goes down to `200`. Am I doing anything wrong in Tensorflow or why are the loss values that small? I can't really track the loss values in `tensorboard` since they are so small. Can anyone help me?

Comment: It looks like you're computing the output between two placeholders and not doing any treatment to `logits` before using it in the loss, is that true? Could you show a bit more of the code?

Comment: Oh no! the placeholders are just for illustration! My last layer looks roughly like this: `logits = tf.nn.conv2d(inputs, weights, [1,strides,strides,1], padding='VALID', data_format='NHWC')` @FlorentinHennecker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first loss you propose is the better one (the second introduces an unnecessary `sqrt`).

Values equal to or smaller than 1 seem to be the only possible values since the range of values you provide is within 0 and 1 - so the biggest possible error is 1.

If you have trouble visualising the loss in tensorboard, try showing the graphs using a log scale (one of the two buttons under the graphs)

Comment: Problem ist my error starts with a value greater than 1 which confuses me... Plus my values get so small that the value is zero since the values are like value.e-10.

Comment: You might want to show your code then